# List sbt `Task` tags

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a way to list the [tags associated with a Task](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Parallel-Execution.html#Tagging+Tasks) in `sbt`?

`inspect` and `show` don’t seem to have anything there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cool and powerful aspect of sbt is that the build definition it generates is a regular Scala application meaning we can inspect its objects, like we would in any other Scala application, by simply invoking member methods to query their state. Executing `sbt` starts the REPL for the special DSL build language, however we can drop to a lower level by executing

```
sbt consoleProject
```

to start true [Scala REPL](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Console-Project.html):

> starts the Scala interpreter with access to your project definition
>   and to sbt... `consoleProject` can be useful for creating and
>   modifying your build in the same way that the Scala interpreter is
>   normally used to explore writing code. Note that this gives you raw
>   access to your build.

There exists a public [`tags`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/56cf50ff2385eb8468e2724d4d0e3a9262adc335/tasks-standard/src/main/scala/sbt/Action.scala#L73) method

```
final case class Task[T](info: Info[T], work: Action[T]) {
  ...
  def tags: TagMap = info get tagsKey getOrElse TagMap.empty
}
```

so there must be a way to invoke it (even if there might not be a ready top level command for it such as `inspect`). Say we have the following [tagged](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Parallel-Execution.html#Tagging+Tasks) task definition in `build.sbt`

```
lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("Vulcan greeting")
hello := Def.task(println("Live long and prosper")).tag(Tags.CPU, Tags.Compile).value
```

After executing `consoleProject` our build definition is imported

```
scala> import _root_.scala.xml.{TopScope=>$scope}
import _root_.sbt._
import _root_.sbt.Keys._
import _root_.sbt.nio.Keys._
import _root_.sbt.ScriptedPlugin.autoImport._
import _root_.sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.CorePlugin
import _root_.sbt.ScriptedPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.SbtPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.SemanticdbPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
import _root_.sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin
import $d408b7d79eabe42459a4.root
import currentState._
import extracted._
import cpHelpers._
```

Now we can make use of [`Extracted#get`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/56cf50ff2385eb8468e2724d4d0e3a9262adc335/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Extracted.scala#L35) to get the `TaskKey` and explore it like so

```
scala> extracted.get(hello).tags
res1: sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions.TagMap = Map(Tag(cpu) -> 1, Tag(compile) -> 1)
```

Furthermore, note the `import $d408b7d79eabe42459a4`. We can use this object to access regular val/def members, for example, say we had defined in `build.sbt`

```
def helloTask = Def.task { println("Live long and prosper") } tag(Tags.CPU, Tags.Compile)
```

then we could access `helloTask` like so

```
scala> $d408b7d79eabe42459a4.helloTask.evaluate(structure.data).tags
res0: sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions.TagMap = Map(Tag(cpu) -> 1, Tag(compile) -> 1)
```

Both approaches show the required `Map(Tag(cpu) -> 1, Tag(compile) -> 1)`.

---

Addressing the comment [`compileTask`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/56cf50ff2385eb8468e2724d4d0e3a9262adc335/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1746) does not seem to be tagged thus

```
scala> get(Compile/compile).tags
res8: sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions.TagMap = Map()
```

however, for example, [`updateFull`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/56cf50ff2385eb8468e2724d4d0e3a9262adc335/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L2523) task is indeed tagged

```
updateFull := (updateTask tag (Tags.Update, Tags.Network)).value
```

hence

```
scala> get(updateFull).tags
res9: sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions.TagMap = Map(Tag(update) -> 1, Tag(network) -> 1)
```

Comment: Fantastic insight! Can you expand the answer a bit? Based on the https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Parallel-Execution.html#Built-in+Tags+and+Rules I would expect compile to have a `Compile` tag however, when I check for a given project I get an empty map:
```
scala> $dfcea8db51ca564da9af.common./(Compile./(compile)).evaluate(structure.data).tags
res13: sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions.TagMap = Map()
```